# Why is avg. block time growing so much latley

Tags: difficulty, block-interval

how come average block time is growing this much latley? In March it was around 14.5 and today is around 24. I know that hash rate is growing fast, but shouldn't every difficulty adjustment reset avg. block time to around 14-15?

Thnx,
Tomo

Answer (score 5):

This is due to the [Ethereum 'Ice Age'](https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/guides/what-is-the-ethereum-ice-age/) - an incentive implemented in the code to switch from the current Proof of Work consensus mechanism to a Proof of Stake consensus mechanism or as Vitalik puts it to "prevent protocol stagnation".

[From a Tweet Vitalk made:](https://twitter.com/vitalikbuterin/status/901284981556641793?lang=en)
[image]